# how to fix the Invalid Object ID Mongo Exception

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, pecl

I have this code

```
public function deactivateDuplicateDevices(Document\Device $oDevice, Document\Passenger $oPassenger)
{
    $passengerId = new \MongoId(oPassenger->getId());
    $deviceId = new \MongoId($oDevice->getId());

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('Device')
        ->update()
        ->multiple(true)
        ->field('activated')->set(false)
        ->field('passenger')->unsetField()->equals($passengerId)
        ->field('_id')->notEqual($deviceId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

which works just fine on my dev server but crashes on my local machine.

running `pecl list` on dev returns

```
APC     3.1.13  beta
amqp    1.2.0   stable
intl    3.0.0   stable
mongo   1.3.7   stable
```

and on local returns:

```
mongo   1.5.6   stable
xdebug  2.2.5   stable
```

the crash message on my machine is

```
"name":"MongoException","message":"Invalid object ID"},"code":500}
```

I'v tried downgrading my local version of mongo but i couldn't figure it out with pecl's poor documentation. for example i tried this:

```
sudo pecl upgrade -f -c channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.3.7
```

but i keep on getting `channel does not exist` for all my channel permutations.

also running `mongod --version` locally returns **db version v2.6.0** and on dev returns **db version v2.4.3**

this is the full stack trace

```
{"response":{"file":"\/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/Mapping\/Types\/IdType.php","line":37,"trace":"#0 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/Mapping\/Types\/IdType.php(37): MongoId->__construct(1)\n#1 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/Mapping\/ClassMetadataInfo.php(1291): Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Mapping\\Types\\IdType->convertToDatabaseValue(1)\n#2 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/Persisters\/DocumentPersister.php(990): Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Mapping\\ClassMetadataInfo->getDatabaseIdentifierValue(1)\n#3 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/Persisters\/DocumentPersister.php(861): Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Persisters\\DocumentPersister->prepareQueryElement('passenger', 1, NULL, true)\n#4 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/Persisters\/DocumentPersister.php(836): Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Persisters\\DocumentPersister->prepareSubQuery(Array)\n#5 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/Query\/Expr.php(129): Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Persisters\\DocumentPersister->prepareNewObj(Array)\n#6 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/Query\/Builder.php(239): Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Query\\Expr->getNewObj()\n#7 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/src\/St\/AppBundle\/Repository\/DeviceRepository.php(132): Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\Query\\Builder->getQuery()\n#8 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/src\/St\/AppBundle\/Model\/PassengerManager.php(207): St\\AppBundle\\Repository\\DeviceRepository->deactivateDuplicateDevices(Object(St\\AppBundle\\Document\\Device), Object(MongoDBODMProxies\\__CG__\\St\\AppBundle\\Document\\Passenger))\n#9 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/src\/St\/ApiBundle\/Controller\/PassengerController.php(96): St\\AppBundle\\Model\\PassengerManager->register(Object(St\\AppBundle\\Document\\Device), '6651')\n#10 [internal function]: St\\ApiBundle\\Controller\\PassengerController->verifyRegistrationAction()\n#11 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/jms\/cg\/src\/CG\/Proxy\/MethodInvocation.php(63): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(EnhancedProxy_5e2a7e5669a027f8d79b4b96c7288b294d024637\\__CG__\\St\\ApiBundle\\Controller\\PassengerController), Array)\n#12 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/jms\/security-extra-bundle\/JMS\/SecurityExtraBundle\/Security\/Authorization\/Interception\/MethodSecurityInterceptor.php(120): CG\\Proxy\\MethodInvocation->proceed()\n#13 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/jms\/cg\/src\/CG\/Proxy\/MethodInvocation.php(58): JMS\\SecurityExtraBundle\\Security\\Authorization\\Interception\\MethodSecurityInterceptor->intercept(Object(CG\\Proxy\\MethodInvocation))\n#14 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/app\/cache\/dev\/jms_diextra\/proxies\/St-ApiBundle-Controller-PassengerController.php(21): CG\\Proxy\\MethodInvocation->proceed()\n#15 [internal function]: EnhancedProxy_5e2a7e5669a027f8d79b4b96c7288b294d024637\\__CG__\\St\\ApiBundle\\Controller\\PassengerController->verifyRegistrationAction()\n#16 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/app\/bootstrap.php.cache(1426): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#17 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/app\/bootstrap.php.cache(1390): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1)\n#18 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/app\/bootstrap.php.cache(1566): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true)\n#19 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/app\/bootstrap.php.cache(617): Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request), 1, true)\n#20 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/web\/app_dev.php(31): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request))\n#21 \/Users\/abdullah\/dev\/php\/smartTaxi\/vendor\/symfony\/symfony\/src\/Symfony\/Bundle\/FrameworkBundle\/Resources\/config\/router.php(30): require('\/Users\/abdullah...')\n#22 {main}","name":"MongoException","message":"Invalid object ID"},"code":500}
```

in php storm if i highlight the mongoid type it shows me this

[image]

ideas?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add Object ID. Also you can check this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

Answer (score 0):

so basically the way i did this was simply by going to the mongo package page on the pecl website [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo).. i downloaded [mongo-1.3.7.tgz](http://pecl.php.net/get/mongo-1.3.7.tgz). then I simply ran this command on it (after uninstalling the original 1.5.6 version `using pecl uninstall mongo`):

```
pecl install mongo-1.3.7.tgz
```

and that was it! So clearly this is a version specific issue.. a command that got deprecated or something..